# How to ignore shebang "#!/usr/bin/env bash" in a chrooted SSH Plesk hosted webspace environment

Tags: bash, environment-variables, plesk, shebang, hubzilla

Is there any way to ignore a shebang from a script to run scripts globally via "/bin/bash"?

I have a PLESK-hosted webspace, with SSH chrooted to my web-home. I tried to install hubzilla, but most scripts in there return errors because they use the shebang

```
"#!/usr/bin/env bash"
```

In my home, "/usr" only contains a folder "/lib", and I do not have (nor will be granted) rights to create a matching directory or a symlink (bash is located in "/bin" and is standard interpreter for ssh).  Adding

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"
```

to ".profile" does not solve the problem, either.

I could modify all scripts with that shebang to "#!/bin/bash" - But then I would have to re-do that after each update...? Is hubzilla just not for PLESK hosted webspaces? The hoster suggests a vserver, instead, but I want to avoid server administration.

Update: Problem solved by Barmar! Calling the script using bash directly works.

Overal solution for the use case at hand: Hubzilla's script (add_addon_repo - and probably others) calls further commands that are not available via SSH (next problem: git is not accessible via command line, just panel). So I guess hubzilla uses just more functionality than (at least this) webspace offers. So I will reactivate my vhost.

Comment: Why do you not want to provide `/usr/bin/env` in your chroot? Mechanically changing the first line is trivial with `find` + `sed`; did you google this?

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29620/10454

Comment: This is one reason why shebangs should be added by the *installer* (who has knowledge about the file-system layout of the target environment) rather than the author of the script.

Comment: macOS, at least, doesn't require an absolute path. `#!bash` will use whatever version of `bash` is found first in your path, no `env` needed.

Comment: @triplee: no writing rights.

Comment: @Keith Thompson: Thank you. If it solves the problem, I could not find the sepcific content that does.

Comment: @chepner: yes. Unfortunately, the script is not done my me. As to macOS, I doubt my webhoster uses it, so maybe this can help others who do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the script with `bash` explicitly, rather than as a command:

```
/bin/bash scriptname
```